# Why can't I see the slide library in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, slidelibrary

I've a SharePoint 2010 Enterprise environment that I'm trying to create a slide library on. Unfortunately I can't see the template option to create one.

As per this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/3fc5bbf4-fa0a-4498-8177-b56e4f91a1a3 I tried to enable one of the following features on my site collection:

- Office SharePoint Server Standard Site features Office SharePoint
- Server Standard Site Features

However I couldn't see either of them to enable. What is the missing component here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have

- A Team Site (may or may not work with other site templates)
- enterprise features enabled
- Powerpoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 2010 Entrerprise with Full Control permissions

1. In Site Settings
2. Under Site Actions
3. Manage site features
4. Activate Sharepoint Server Standard Site features
5. Slide Library should now be availble under create new library

I know you've referenced the Activate Sharepoint Server Standard Site features option above but it wasn't clear to me where you were looking for it so I hope this helps :-)